# How do I get the common navigator contents?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, cnf

it sounds like the entire contents of the Package Explorer view is exposed via the Common Navigator Framework.

How can I access this data though? I want to see the names of all the projects, files, and methods within. The closest I've gotten is:

```
INavigatorContentService n = NavigatorContentServiceFactory.INSTANCE.createContentService(SampleView.ID);
ITreeContentProvider tcp = n.createCommonContentProvider();
Object[] els = tcp.getElements(new Object());
```

but els is empty, probably because I have no idea what to pass into getElements.

Some interesting debugging: when I use the debugger to dive into the getElements call, it looks like findRootContentExtensions finds a bunch of NavigatorContentDescriptor's which look promising, but then they are not returned because they fail the isActive and isRootExtension checks. It then goes on to try to find other things to return, but it takes into account the object I pass in, and proceeds to not work. I haven't a clue what's going on.

All the documentation I've found focuses on adding a new view using the CNF, but not looking at the workspace's existing contents. Is there any good documentation for this? Thanks!

Comment: Package Explorer doesn't use the common navigator (Project Explorer does). You can see projects, folders and files using the resources API. For the contents of Java files you use the JDT Abstract Syntax Tree API.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I imagined that the JDT exposed its java structure in some sort of common format, so that the Project Explorer could display it; I'd assume the Project Explorer can't think in terms of JDT. Does the JDT not give the CNF a custom ITreeContentProvider/ILabelProvider that I can access in a way similar to how the Project Explorer view does?

Comment: I don't know what the Project Explorer uses, but trying to get the info from a view is the wrong approach - what happens if the view is not open? The [JDT AST](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) provides an extensive API which you can use directly.

Comment: Sorry for my apparent resistance to using the JDT AST, I'm just trying to be certain there's no language agnostic method first before I go down that path. My thought in this question is that maybe I can read not from the view, but from whatever it is that the view is reading from. I imagine that there's some way that JDT, CDT, etc all register their contents in a way that can be read by the project explorer and other language-agnostic components. If there is a way, then that would be the preferred way to get the information I'm looking for.